# Wrong cutting-off of filter's string in review queue

Tags: bug, review, design, localization, russian-stackoverflow

My question is about Stack Overflow in Russian, but probably it affects another localized sites. <s>I can't check them due to lack of reputation.</s>

The string which contains the list of currently selected filters in the [close votes review queue](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/) is cut-off the wrong way. As a result, the badge progress indicator is shifted down:

> [image: ruSO]

Turned out that I can view such page for any site by type an address in the browser's, e.g. in Japanese SO:

> ```
> https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/close
> ```

And seems this bug affects only sites with Russian language interface like [ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/) and [rus.SE](https://rus.stackexchange.com/review/close/)